# Is there a way to determine if the user is accessing application for the first time from the Azure AAD tokens?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using Open ID Connect authorization code flow and Azure Active Directory is the tokens provider. Is there an easy way to understand if this is the first time the user is logging in to my application simply by looking at the tokens?

Comment: No, there is no such claim in the token.  You need to maintain the information in your application. For example, save the user information to the database at the first time, and check if the user is existed every time you get a new request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the ID token you get from Azure AD not include information telling you if this is the first time a user signs into your app.